# Autoplay video (no sound and muted) on Firefox Android

Tags: android, firefox, html5-video, autoplay

I use a video element as background. The source files have no sound, and to be sure I put attribute muted in there.

It starts playing automatically on Opera (for Android and Windows), MX5, Firefox(66) for Android and  Firefox (82) for Windows. However, when I start the page in Firefox (81) for Android it doesn't start (until user event calls .play() ).

Is it true Firefox now blocks all videos be default (even without sound) or is this a bug and is there a way to work around it?

I mean, I could go back to gif instead, but they are so big in size.

```
<style>
  .background {
    width: 100vw;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -9999;
  }
</style>

<video id="background" class="background" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
    <source src="vid/background_vp9.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="vid/background.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="vid/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <img class="background" src="img/background.png" alt="background">
  </video>
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but I browsed the entire net and didn't find any information about Firefox blocking muted autoplay videos

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @TheKalpit O, yes, I found a solution. I made a screen that said "Click here to enter the website" that would start the video. However, at some point Firefox for Android was fixed and is now playing video without sound without the need for a user driven event, as it should. The website is not online anymore, so haven't checked the most recent version. Do you still experience the same problem?